# Is it possible to play Youtube stream as sound in Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, youtube

For example, if I want to stream a live video from Youtube as a stream in audio player, can I do it in Flutter? I can't seem to figure out how to get a direct link to the sound, so I don't know if it is possible. If not, do you guys have any alternatives?

At the moment I am using Audioplayers library, but if it can't support streaming, any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Hello, did you ever figure out how to do this? I am trying to find a solution for the same requirement. I have found many audio players in flutter but they all seem to lack documentation with file support or maybe they just don't do that.